# Nesting loops within For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a long line of code which runs fine, but I was wondering if a nested If loop within the outer For loop would shorten the code, and if so, what would be the appropriate way to write this nested loop.

This is for a JavaScript array which has nested objects called by counter i.  Within each object are key:value pairs.  Myopia, Maple, and truckdriver are the keys, and the returned values are numbers 0 to infinity.

```
for (let i = 0; i < z; i++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
      y[i].truckdriver = 0;
  }
  for (let i = 49; i < (z - 1); i++) {
      if (y[i].Myopia > 0 && y[i].Maple < y[i].Myopia) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 0;
      } else if ((i + 1) >= z) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 0;
      } else if (y[i].Myopia > 0 && y[i + 1].Maple < y[i].Myopia) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 1;
      } else if ((i + 2) >= z) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 0;
      } else if (y[i].Myopia > 0 && y[i + 2].Maple < y[i].Myopia) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 2;
      } else if ((i + 3) >= z) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 0;
      } else if (y[i].Myopia > 0 && y[i + 3].Maple < y[i].Myopia) {
           y[i].truckdriver = 3;
      } else {
           y[i].truckdriver = 0;
      }
  }
  for (let i = (z - 1); (i < z); i++) {
      y[i].truckdriver = 0;
  }

}
```

I hope to shorten this code while retaining its functionality.

Comment: Can you show a sample of `y` so we see the structure? What is `z`; The length of `y`? And could you explain the logic? You update the truck driver property according to what the next object contains? So I guess the easiest would be to show original `y`, and what `y` looks like after the loops finish.

Comment: Questions about improving the style of working code are more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Comment: But you need to fix the typo on the last `[i].truckdriver = 0;` it's missing `y`.

Comment: Thanks Barmer, I would like to move it there, and you're right, the last for statement lost its y.  I corrected it

Comment: Thanks Shilly.  You're right, z is the length of array y.   Its purpose is break the function if it starts trying to use the counter i past the end of the array y.  y is in the format of [{Myopia:value, Mable:value}, {Myopia:value, Mable:value},{Myopia:value, Mable:value}], and it returns [{Myopia:value, Mable:value, truckdriver:value}, {Myopia:value, Mable:value, truckdriver:value}, {Myopia:value, Mable:value, truckdriver:value}, {Myopia:value, Mable:value, truckdriver:value}]  y is basically parsed JSON returning objects wrapped in an array

Answer (score 0):

Some minor room for shortening.

- You can dedupe the 1st and 3rd for loops with a single for loop setting all `truckdriver` values to `0` initially.
- This also allows removing the last else case, as `truckdriver` is already `0`
- You can remove the branch `(i+1) >= z`, as always false since you iterate `i` while `< (z - 1)`
- Extracting the check `y[i].Myopia > 0` makes your code longer in # of lines, but shorter in character count and much easier to read
- Lastly, as you yourself mentioned, the if statements and their then clauses are very similar and can be reused inside a for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < z; i++)
  y[i].truckdriver = 0;

for (let i = 49; i < (z - 1); i++) {
  if (y[i].Myopia > 0)
    continue;

  for (let j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
    if (i + j < z && y[i + j].MAPLE < y[i].Myopia) {
      y[i].truckdriver = j;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  You're right, the last for statement is redundant.  I was wondering if a new counter j could be assigned to the "+1", "+2", "+3" because the actual code runs to ..."+50" and is extremely long

Comment: Good point! updated my answer to do as you suggested, reuse the if statement with different indices.

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant.  Only thing is last if statement needs to read if(i + (j+1) < z    and it runs fine.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry should be ((i + j) < z    and it runs fine.  Thanks